# Pandas resample changes dates

Tags: pandas, pandas-resample

Why is `df.resample()` changing the dates when I resample?

`X`

[image: Before]

What I want this to do is insert one row with index '2014-07-01' and value NaN.

`X.resample('12M').last()`

[image: after]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `MS`

```
out = df.resample('12MS').first()
Out[33]: 
              0
2014-07-01  1.0
2015-07-01  NaN
2016-07-01  2.0
2017-07-01  3.0
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. Can you explain the difference, and where I can find more info about these codes?

Comment: @MoseWintner MS is for Month start , default is Month End ~